# Is there a name for the corresponding notion of inductive subset in the context of well-ordered sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

This is a question of terminology.  I can't avoid being a little verbose before getting to it.

The principle of mathematical induction states that, for any subset $e$ of $\omega$ (the set of natural numbers), $$\varnothing \in e \land \forall x \; (x \in e \implies x^+ \in e) \implies e = \omega$$ where $x^+ = x \cup \{ x \}$ is the successor of $x$.
The property $$\varnothing \in e \land \forall x \; (x \in e \implies x^+ \in e)$$ of $e$ is called inductivity, and the principle of mathematical induction can be stated succinctly as "$\omega$ is its only inductive subset".

Similarly, the principle of transfinite induction in a well-ordered set $w$ states that, for any subset $e$ of $w$, $$\forall x \in w \; (s(x) \subset e \implies x \in e) \implies e = w$$ where $s(x) = \{ y \in w \;|\; y < x \}$ is the strict initial section of $x$ in $w$.  My question is this: is there a fairly standard name for the property $\forall x \in w \; (s(x) \subset e \implies x \in e)$ (the term "transductive" comes to mind!) that would allow for a succinct statement of the principle of transfinite induction ("a well-ordered set is its only transductive subset"). I have never seen a name for this property and not been able to find one on the web.

Comment: See [down set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_set).

Comment: @GitGud The property that I'm talking about involves down sets (the initial sections) but is not the same as being a down set.